# scrapy run spider from path

Tags: python, scrapy

A number of suggestions on running scrapy suggest doing this in order to start scrapy via script, or to debug in an IDE, etc:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute(("scrapy runspider spider-file-name.py").split())
```

This works, so long as the script is placed in the project directory, but if not try to give it an absolute or relative path. For example:

```
import os

from scrapy import cmdline

this_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
base_path = this_file_path.replace('bootstrap', '')
full_path = base_path + "path/to/spiders/some-spider.py"
print full_path

cmdline.execute(("scrapy runspider " + full_path).split())
```

With this, I get:

```
2016-09-28 10:49:29 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-09-28 10:49:29 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

spider-main.py: error: Unable to load '/Users/name/intellij-workspace/crawling/scrape/scrape/spiders/some-spider.py': No module named items
```

Is there a way to run and debug scrapy spiders from an absolute path? Ideally, I need to have this to debug in an IDE.

Comment: Passing a full path works fine. Your setup is most likely the issue

Comment: What would be wrong with my setup that would cause this? I created the project using the scrapy project and spider creation commands.

Answer (score 3):

It's highly advised to use a distributed crawling software but if you really want to do it like this just for some dirty testing here it is

```
import subprocess

project_path="/Users/name/intellij-workspace/crawling/scrape"
subprocess.Popen(["scrapy","runspider","scrape/spiders/some-spider.py"],cwd=project_path)
```

Comment: You don't need to call chdir, you can pass a cwd argument to Popen

Comment: "Distributed crawling software" like what? Nutch? StormCrawler?

Comment: I've tried this, even capturing the Popen in a variable and dumping out stdout and stderror and still, nothing. Both of those outputs just say None

Comment: I've also dumped the project_path into a terminal and ran the command there with the same inputs as the Popen function; it works in the terminal, not from the python script

Comment: try it in the python shell, for me everything is working fine with `Popen`. I'm using python 2

Comment: Ok, yes. It works in the python shell. I should have mentioned, I am trying to run it in intellij - I'd like to be able to debug it.